# Convert float to time in Java?

Tags: java, web-services, time, floating-point

*Is it possible to convert a float to a time in Java?*

I'm new to web services and I'm trying to invoke a simple sunrise/sunset time webservice, the WSDL for this is [here](http://www.webservicex.net/sunsetriseservice.asmx?WSDL)

I've passed the service a latitude (34.0888), longitude (-118.40612), day, month and year and I have got values back:

**sunrise: 13.6935135
sunset: 26.607845**

But the values are floats, does anyone know why this would be? Or if it is possible to work out a time from them? I thought it might be unix time but I've not had much luck with that.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: are you sure those aren't doubles?

Comment: According to the WSDL, they are floats, but do not have any docs as to what they represent.  Converting to time is strait forward once you know what they represent

Comment: The webservice returns floats. I can assign them to a double variable but then I just get 13.093513488769531 and 26.607845306396484.

Comment: those results are strange.  What day, month and year did you pass in?  What happens if you change seasons, do you see evidence that the values follow standard seasonal patterns?

Comment: Yeah I don't know what they represent, I was hoping there might of been a common way dates/times are represented as floats

Answer (score 3):

That's probably a number of hours relative to UTC. I would try something like this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, (int) sunrise);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, (sunrise * 60) % 60);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, (sunrise * 3600) % 3600);
```

Then display the date in the timezone you want with a `DateFormat`:

```
DateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat();
fmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Paris")); 
System.out.println(fmt.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Comment: Thanks, ok its outputting the correct date but the time is off. It always comes out on the hour with no mins. I'm getting sunrise of 15:00 in CA state with the above code, and 08.00 in uk.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't look like a trivial thing to calculate... there is a full package to handle that here : https://github.com/mikereedell/sunrisesunsetlib-java

Comment: I agree on stop using a unspecified webservice and adopt a (local) library to do the calculation!

Comment: Why don't you try a helloWorld service then !? ;-)

Comment: ok... I think you picked a bad one! To start, I suggest to try with amazon's web services (or other big company's web services). Usually they are well documented and you can focus on your errors (and not on the other party's errors). (or a HelloWorld service ;-) )

Answer (score 1):

```
Float sunriseFloat = new Float(sunrise);  
Float sunsetFloat = new Float(sunset);

    Date startDate = new Date(sunriseFloat.longValue());  
    Date endDate = new Date(sunsetFloat.longValue());
```

Comment: Not sure why the downvote the question is how do you convert floats into time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm seeing an error with your code as my sunrise value is float:

Cannot invoke longValue() on the primitive type float

Comment: @ostegg548 updated.  Wasn't even thinking about the boxing back and forth.

Comment: Would this code be for unix time? I'm getting a date of Thu Jan 01 1970. I don't think it is returning a unix time, thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is not a java problem, and you found a webservice with a underspecified interface. I googled for a solution and I found several libraries able to calculate sunrise and sunset. For example, this was one of the first results: http://www.jstott.me.uk/jsuntimes/